# find <ul> id based on text of <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have li with unique text and i want to get the  id on that text.

```
<ul id="test1">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li>
 </ul>

<ul id="test2">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('Account')">Test Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the UL id, whose li anchor tag onclick function contains text is **users**.

Comment: U want to find it after `onclick` or `onLoad` and populate the ul/li ? ?

Comment: i want to find it onLoad. As i get the text users from my url and based on that text i need to display the menu.

Comment: try this: $(this).parent().attr('id');

Comment: @SyedSajid i am getting undefined error

Comment: use it under a function which is triggered on some event of this 'li' it will give you undefined if you use it on its own...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to do this:

```
var $usersUl = $('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('onclick').indexOf('users') != -1;
}).closest('ul');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4RZeL/1/)

It should be noted however that having your UI rely on a parameter in a JS function call is a little unsightly, if not verging on a hack. If you can, change the HTML to include some `data` attributes and filter by those:

```
<ul id="test1">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')" data-type="users">My Link</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="test2">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('Account')" data-type="account">Test Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
var $users = $('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('users');
}).closest('ul');
```

Comment: `.closest("ul")` at the end. OP wants the `<ul>` ID, rather than the anchor. Otherwise +1

Comment: How to get the ul id. in above code i will get anchor tag

Comment: `$users.prop('id')`, or just add `.prop('id')` to the end of the JS above, and the `$users` variable will then contain the `id`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 

How to toggle display block or none. If my code is as follows

<ul id="test1,test2,abc" style="display:none;">
      <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction('users')">My Link</a></li>
     </ul>

i will get the text test1 or test2 or abc. I want to find this ul on this text and i want to set it to display : block

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EK3zr/)**

```
var id = $('ul > li > a[onclick*="\'users\'"]').closest('ul').attr('id');
```

Or to include the function name as well:

```
var id = $('ul > li > a[onclick="myfunction(\'users\')"]').closest('ul').attr('id');
```

Comment: This is far from generic.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this is far from "generic"?

Comment: My impression was that he was asking for a generic way. My bad. This does exactly what he was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an onclick in this case, try something like this:

```
<ul id="test1">
  <li><a href="#" data-value="users">My Link</a></li>
 </ul>

<ul id="test2">
  <li><a href="#" data-value="Account">Test Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then jQuery:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    parent = $(this).parent(); // your UL element
    value = $(this).data('value'); // your parameter, you can use it now
    // Rest of your function right here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
$('ul a').click(function(){  // click event for anchor tag which is inside ul

if($(this).indexOf("users") == -1) // check if text contains users
{

console.log($(this).parent("ul").attr("id")); // get its parent ul id
}

})
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution in very brief?

Comment: added comments with lines

Answer (score 0):

Pass the current object in event handler and use to get the id of parent `ul` using `closest()`, `onclick="myfunction(this,'users')"`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/4RSNv/)**

*HTML*

```
<ul id="test1">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction(this,'users')">My Link</a></li>
 </ul>

<ul id="test2">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunction(this,'Account')">Test Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

*Javascript*

```
function myfunction(obj, parm)
{
   alert($(obj).closest('ul').attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a[onclick*="users"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());   
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CLgEL/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li a').on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).closest('ul').prop('id'));
    });
});
```

Here is my fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/58CTf/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function myfunction(param, event) {
    console.log(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.id);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution in very brief.

Comment: event.target will refer to the "clicked" a (anchor) and  whose immediate parent is li and Li's immediate parent is UL. so to get the ID of UL I have written event.target.parentElement.parentElement.id .

Answer (score 0):

try this this works great(use parent function)

```
    $(function(){
    $("ul li").find("a:contains(Link)").parent().parent().attr("id");
})
```